# Nanoseconds to DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, .net-4.6

I am using .Net version 4.6 and I am using `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` to convert nanoseconds to DateTimeOffset.

```
long j = 1580122686878258600;
var X = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt64(j * 0.000001));
```

I am storing the nanoseconds as `long`, still I have to do conversion to `Int64` while multiplying with 0.000001 to convert nano seconds to milli seconds.

Is there other better way ?

Comment: Just divide by `1000000L`?

Comment: Aren't long and Int64 the same thing?

Comment: That number has no offset so you have no idea what timezone it refers to. Never mind the fast approaching Y2K38 problem. Don't use longs to store time. All languages and databases support date types

Comment: `long` and `Int64` are the same thing. `Int64` is just an alias for `long`.

Comment: @TanveerBadar: Yes, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) it is.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, I get the value from API call as JSON key = date value = nanoseconds. Am I am doing wrong by storing as long?

Comment: BTW that code works and returns `2020-01-27T10:58:06`

Comment: @user584018 yes, the defacto standard is to use the full ISO8601 format, ie `2020-01-27T10:58:06Z` or `2020-01-27T10:58:06+2:00`. That API contains a bug already, and you have no idea what the actuall offset is

Comment: @user584018 just write a method and call it a day.

Comment: @NotTheBatman Actually, that's not accurate. First, `long` is c# alias to `System.Int64`, not the other way around, and second, as Jared Parsons wrote in his blog - [they are not always interchangeable.](https://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2019/04/08/string-vs-String-is-not-about-style.html) When using c#, it's best practice to always use the language's aliases over the class names, as demonstrated in that blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you don't want to convert this to (long) again, you can instead divide by `1000000` instead of multiplying by `0.000001`.

But if you need to multiple, then no, you must convert the result of multiplying a `long` and a `double` back to a `long` in this case.  First, the value `0.000001` is of type `double`.  Second, the compiler will imply a conversion of `long` to `double` for the multiplication between these two types, and the result will be a `double` as well.  The reason for the implied conversion is that there will be loss of precision (the decimal places) when converting back to `long`.  The method `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds()` only accepts a single `long` parameter (long and Int64 are the same data type, long is just an alias for Int64), so you have to convert your result back.

In the case of dividing by `1000000`, division by two `long` values still results in the division, but any decimal places are truncated.

In both cases, you may want to consider the effect of rounding and precision loss, if desired.  You get a different value if you use a nano value of `1580122686878999999`.  For multiplication of `long` and `double` (i.e. `(long)(1580122686878999999 * 0.000001)`) results in `1580122686879`.  But using division of `long`'s, you instead get `1580122686878`.

I have some side comments on the implementation, as well, offering some alternatives:

If you don't like the `Convert.ToInt64()` notation/call itself, then you can use a standard cast (i.e. `(long)(j * 0.000001)`).  If you don't like doing this, you can construct the `DateTimeOffset` using a constructor that accepts "ticks" instead, which you can get from a `TimeSpan` struct, which has a `FromMilliseconds()` method that accepts a `double`, (e.g. `new DateTimeOffset(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(j * 0.000001).Ticks, TimeSpan.Zero)`).  The cast seems to be the most straightforward and concise code, though.

Further, expanding on the "ticks" constructor above, the best solution might be that you instead divide down to "ticks", which are 100-nanosecond and more precise than milliseconds.  In this case you can achieve "ticks" by dividing nanoseconds by 100 (multiplying by 0.01) to gain even more precision, e.g. `new DateTimeOffset((long)(j * 0.01), TimeSpan.Zero)`.  I only offer this with the thought that you may want the most precision possible from the initial nanoseconds value.